# uploading images to the redirected folder using codeignitor

Tags: codeigniter-3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iaAY.jpg)I want to upload my pictures to the uploads directory, but it seems when i send a post request by clicking on my submit button,my code runs but it doesnot insert the submited image to the uploads directory instead it runs the code below

```
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $post_image = 'no_image.jpg';

    }
```

thus causing it to display no_image.jpg in my database. So i have tried editing it but it seems the code can't upload, so am wondering what could be wrong with my code.

That's part of my controller file.

```
public function Edit_RoomType()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Rooms_model';


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('room','RoomType','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Amount','Price Tag','required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
                $this->load->view('templates/header_Admin');
                $this->load->view('Admin/Edit_RoomType', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer_Admin');
    } else {

        //image upload
        $config['upload_path'] ='./assets/uploads';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] ='2048';
        $config['max_width'] ='500';
        $config['max_height'] ='500';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $post_image = 'no_image.jpg';

        } else {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            //setting table field
            $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        }


           $this->Rooms_model->create_room($post_image);
          redirect('Admin');  
    }



}
```

below is part of my model file

```
 public function create_room($post_image)
    {
        $Room_type = url_title($this->input->post('room'));
        $data = array(
            'Room_type' => $Room_type,
            'Amount' => $this->input->post('Amount'),
            'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
            'post_image' => $post_image

        );

        return $this->db->insert('RoomType',$data);
    }
```

Comment: What's the result of $_FILES?  And change upload_path to `$config['upload_path'] =FCPATH.'assets/uploads';`

Comment: same results are returned

Comment: That's two questions i asked .. is there a file passed?

Comment: no The $_FILES is a super global field that will capture the name of the image inserted

Comment: @SherifSalah thanks alot for your  help. I think i got the problem that was disturbing my code..In the echo form_open i had forgot to put there the multipart. So wen i changed it, its now working properly